# How to get the count of duplicate strings in a set using grep, uniq and awk in unix?

Tags: unix, awk, grep, uniq

I have a very large set of strings, one on every line of a file. Many strings occur more than one times in the file at different locations.

I want a frequency count of the strings using unix commands like awk, grep, uniq and so on. I tried few combinations but it didn't work.

what is the exact command to get the frequency count?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks! Shall update it then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To count the occurrences of lines in a file the simplest thing to do is:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
```